# Rear width of 1997 C/K 1500 (WMS to WMS)

Tags: chevrolet, rear-differential, rear-end

The question is simple. I'd like to know what the width of the Chevy C/K 1500 rear is from wheel mounting surface to wheel mounting surface.

Also, is it the same rear that is in the 1997 4WD S10 blazer?

Thanks!

Comment: Will this help: http://www.crankshaftcoalition.com/wiki/Wheelbase,_track_width,_and_differential_measurements

Comment: @SolarMike - SInce I didn't see either vehicle listed, I'm thinking it doesn't.

Comment: @Paulster2 - just one of several sites that come up when searching...